# SQL Alchemy Filter rows based on the values contained in cells of other column

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to python and SQLALCHEMY, and I came across this doubt, whether can we filter rows of the table based on cell values of the column of same table. 
example:

```
Sbranch=value
result=Transaction.query.filter(Transaction.branch==Sbranch)
                          .order_by(desc(Transaction.id)).limit(50).all()
```

if the value of `Sbranch=0`, i want to read all the rows regardless of `Sbranch` value, else i want to filter rows with contains `Transaction.branch==Sbranch`.

I know that it can be achieved by comparing the values of `Sbranch`(if-else conditions),but it gets complicated as the number of such columns increases.
Example:

```
Sbranch=value1
trans_by=value2
trans_to=value3
.
.
result=Transaction.query.filter(Transaction.branch==Sbranch,Transaction.trans_by==value2,Transaction_to==trans_to)
.order_by(desc(Transaction.id)).limit(50).all()
```

I want to apply similar filter with all 3 columns.

I want to know if there is any inbuilt function in SQLALCHEMY to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can optionally add the filter based on the value of `SBranch`

```
query = Transaction.query
if SBranch != 0:
    query = query.filter(Transaction.branch == SBranch)

result = query.order_by(Transaction.id.desc()).limit(50).all()
```

Comment: But this will get complicated as I filter the table with more of such columns. Right now i want filter the table based on cells of  such 6 column.

Comment: Actually, which part of your question is "another column"?

Comment: sorry, it can be any column in the table.

Comment: what can be? `SBranch`? Is it a value, or is it a column?

Comment: Leaving out the filter will make for more efficient query than including a bunch of `IN`s. It also doesn't require including all values.

Answer (score -1):

I think i found the solution, it's not the best but will reduce the work for the developers(not the processor).

```
Sbranch=value
branches=[]
if Sbranch==0:
   # Append all the values into the array for which the rows are filtered
   # for example:
   branches=[1,2,4,7,3,8]
else:
   branches.append(branch)

result=Transaction.query.filter(Transaction.branch.in_(branches))
                          .order_by(desc(Transaction.id)).limit(50).all()
```